# $ifNull operator is not working in my mongo db FIND query for date key fields

Tags: mongodb

I want to pull all orders that have a given date after NVL(modified date, created date).

modifiedDateTime and createdDateTime don’t follow most of the other date fields and I can’t seem to figure out how to do an operator against them.
Not all records have a modifiedDateTime, so when that is missing I want to fall back on the createDateTime. . I attempted something, but can’t get any data logic to work to test it.

- Look for all records where:
- Example Value: Fri Aug 24 23:25:16 UTC 2018
- IF modifiedDateTime exists: Date > modifiedDateTime
- IF modifiedDateTime does not exists: Date > createdDateTime
- SQL version : WHERE NVL(modifiedDateTime, createdDateTime) > '30-SEP-2019'

I tried below but not successful:

```
db.getCollection('createProvisionServiceOrderRepositoryRequest').find(
    {
        'modifiedDateTime': {
            '$ifNull': [
                {'$gte': new ISODate("2019-09-30T00:00:00.000Z")},
                {'createdDateTime': {'$gte': new ISODate("2019-09-30T00:00:00.000Z")}}
            ]
        }
    }
).count()
```

**Two documents sample :**

```
{
        "_id" : "CANO-857098021127729",
        "_class" : "yyyy",
        "customerOrderNumber" : "xxxx",
        "billingAccountNumber" : "123",
        "version" : "1",
        "customerServiceOrderStatus" : "REJECTED",
        "createdDateTime" : "Mon Sep 04 17:35:41 IST 2017"
}
{
        "_id" : "CUMO-971416171118821",
        "_class" : "yyyy",
        "customerOrderNumber" : "xxxx",
        "provisioningServiceOrder" : [
                {
                        "_id" : "string",
                        "provisioningServiceOrderObject" : "Test Data",
                        "status" : "string",
                        "correctionList" : [
                                {
                                        "correctionType" : "string",
                                        "correctionName" : "string",
                                        "correctionAction" : "string",
                                        "correctionOldValue" : "string",
                                        "correctionNewValue" : "string",
                                        "attributeList" : [
                                                {
                                                        "attributeType" : "string",
                                                        "attributeName" : "string",
                                                        "attributeAction" : "string",
                                                        "attributeOldValue" : "string",
                                                        "attributeNewValue" : "string"
                                                }
                                        ]
                                }
                        ]
                }
        ],
        "customerServiceOrderStatus" : "completed",
        "modifiedDateTime" : "Wed Sep 06 07:15:47 UTC 2017"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can simply apply an OR on the `modifiedDateTime` and `createdDateTime` checks. If `modifiedDateTime` is null or is less than the specified date, then only the second condition in the OR block would be evaluated.

We can convert a proper date string to a date object using [$toDate](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toDate/) operator.

**For example:**

```
db.collection.find({
    $expr:{
        $or:[
            {
                $gte:[
                    {
                        $toDate:"$modifiedDateTime"
                    },
                    new ISODate("2017-09-03T00:00:00.000Z")
                ]
            },
            {
                $gte:[
                    {
                        $toDate:"$createdDateTime"
                    },
                    new ISODate("2017-09-03T00:00:00.000Z")
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}).pretty()
```

**For MongoDB 3.4:**

```
db.collection.find({
    $where: function(){
        var selectedDate = new ISODate("2017-09-03T00:00:00.000Z");  
        if(this.modifiedDateTime == null){
            if(this.createdDateTime != null){
                var preparedCreatedDateTime = this.createdDateTime.substring(0,11) + this.createdDateTime.substring(24) + " " + this.createdDateTime.substring(11,19);
                return new Date(preparedCreatedDateTime) > selectedDate;
            }
        }else{
            var preparedModifiedDateTime = this.modifiedDateTime.substring(0,11) + this.modifiedDateTime.substring(24) + " " + this.modifiedDateTime.substring(11,19);
            return new Date(preparedModifiedDateTime) > selectedDate;
        }
        return false;
    }
}).pretty()
```

**Data set:**

```
{
    "_id" : "CANO-857098021127729",
    "_class" : "yyyy",
    "customerOrderNumber" : "xxxx",
    "customerServiceOrderStatus" : "REJECTED",
    "createdDateTime" : "Mon Sep 04 17:35:41 IST 2017"
}
{
    "_id" : "CUMO-971416171118821",
    "_class" : "yyyy",
    "customerOrderNumber" : "xxxx",
    "customerServiceOrderStatus" : "completed",
    "modifiedDateTime" : "Wed Sep 06 07:15:47 UTC 2017"
}
{
    "_id" : "CUMO-971416171118824",
    "_class" : "yyyy",
    "customerOrderNumber" : "xxxx",
    "customerServiceOrderStatus" : "completed",
    "modifiedDateTime" : "Sat Sep 02 07:15:47 UTC 2017"
}
```

**Output:**

```
{
    "_id" : "CANO-857098021127729",
    "_class" : "yyyy",
    "customerOrderNumber" : "xxxx",
    "customerServiceOrderStatus" : "REJECTED",
    "createdDateTime" : "Mon Sep 04 17:35:41 IST 2017"
}
{
    "_id" : "CUMO-971416171118821",
    "_class" : "yyyy",
    "customerOrderNumber" : "xxxx",
    "customerServiceOrderStatus" : "completed",
    "modifiedDateTime" : "Wed Sep 06 07:15:47 UTC 2017"
}
```

Comment: when i try this query getting the below error:Error: error: {
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "unknown top level operator: $expr",
        "code" : 2,
        "codeName" : "BadValue"

Comment: You can use $expr with mongo version 3.6+.

Comment: 3.4-12 mongo percona

Comment: can you help me how to get the query for 3.4-12 version

Comment: Sure. Will revert back in some time.

Comment: If we can make `modifiedDateTime` and `createdDateTime` in the following format: `Sun Sep 03 2017 05:30:00` then we can have a workaround, currently, the year comes at the end which is not getting parsed properly in javascript date function.

Comment: how can we modify in that format as currently we have it in Mon Sep 04 17:35:41 IST 2017?

Comment: @Mamatha Updated the answer. It's not the optimized way but would work :)... I would suggest upgrading to MongoDB 4.2 for cool features.

Comment: Thanks for the update and i am checking with customer.                                             I need help for another query: Problem:
We are seeing a single customerOrderNumber with all versions having “INACTIVE.” It is problem for multiple reasons. I want to pull a list of customerOrderNumbers with ONLY INACTIVE statuses. ( My approach was to pull all customerOrders by status and count, parse it into a relational format, and filter by only customerOrderNumbers with all versions being INACTIVE.

Comment: XXX_ORDERMGMT_1
db.getCollection('customerOrder').aggregate(  [
{ $match: { 'orderDocument.accountInfo.ban': '123456' } },
{ $group: { _id: 
{
customerOrderNumber : '$orderReference.customerOrderNumber', 
status : '$orderReference.customerOrderStatus'
},
count: { $sum: 1 }
},
}] )

Comment: @Mamatha Please ask a separate question so that other devs can also make use of that. :)

Comment: OUTPUT:
/* 1 */
{
"_id" : {
"customerOrderNumber" : "123",
"status" : "COMPLETED"
},
"count" : 1.0
}

/* 2 */
{
"_id" : {
"customerOrderNumber" : "123",
"status" : "INACTIVE"
},
"count" : 2.0
}

Comment: @Mamatha If your current question is answered properly, please accept the answer. I would request you to ask a new question for your next query so that it can reach out to other developers too. :)

Comment: i received this query works. thanks for the same. I have raised another question separately can you pls help me on that as i didn't receive any update still.

Comment: Sure. Please post the link here.